# is there any way so that I could able to move my location and comment fields as shown in the figure

Tags: reactjs, devextreme, devextreme-react

[sample Image that I want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srdZ8.png)So the problem is I'm using devextreme components for my react applications. In building this special page I got struct with a special case in devextreme UI case. I have a row containing headers two lines of headers. first line is the fixed line of headerson top of table containing shed, storagetype,assignedbags,capacity, maxbags, lead,bagsper layer. the second line containing rendering header below to the shed and storagetype, they are location and comment. So when I press the button to add the location should add the new row.
I tryed to perform the same thing but I'm getting the single line row. Please help me

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import apis from "../api-constants";
import './temporarystack.scss';
import DataGrid, { Column } from "devextreme-react/data-grid";
import useGetAPI from "../getAPIS";
import { Button, SelectBox } from "devextreme-react";
import { formatMessage } from "devextreme/localization";

export default function TemporaryStack ({tokenDetails,operation,isTempUsed,temporaryStacksJSON}) {
    
    const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(false);
    const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);
    const [shedOptions, setShedOptions] = useState(null);
    const [threshold,setThreshold]=useState({})
    const storageTypeOptions=[
      {id:1,name:'Gang Way'}, 
      {id:2,name:'Alley Way'}, 
      {id:3,name:'Road Side'}, 
      {id:4,name:'Plinth'}, 
      {id:5,name:'Others'}
    ]
  
  
    useEffect(()=>{
      
      async function Dataapi(){
        const responceforshed=await useGetAPI(apis.GET_GODOWN_UNITS(operation))
        const responceforthreshold=await useGetAPI(apis.GET_BAGWEIGHT_THRESHOLD_MAXIMUXBAGCAPACITY)
        setShedOptions(responceforshed.data)
        setThreshold(responceforthreshold.data)
      }
  
      if(showTable===true){
        Dataapi()
      }
      
    },[operation,tokenDetails,showTable])
    useEffect(()=>{
      temporaryStacksJSON(listData)
    },[listData])
    
    // removing data when Temporary stack is unchecked and initialization state
    const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
      const isChecked = e.target.checked;
      setShowTable(isChecked);
      isTempUsed(isChecked)
      if (!isChecked) {
        setListData([])
      }
    };
    
    // adding new row to the temporary stack
    const addRow = () => {
      const newItem = {
        shed: shedOptions && shedOptions.length > 0 ? shedOptions[0]?.value : '', 
        storageType: storageTypeOptions.length > 0 ? storageTypeOptions[0].name : '',
        assignedBags: '',
        capacity: '',
        maxBags: '',
        lead: '',
        bagsPerLayer: '',
        locationDescription: '',
        comment: '',
      };
      setListData((prevList) => [...prevList, newItem]);
  
    };
  
  
    // to delete a temporary stack
    const deleteRow = (index) => {
      const updatedList = [...listData];
      updatedList.splice(index, 1);
      setListData(updatedList);
    };
  
    // rendering the table or state change for data
    const renderTable = () => {
      if (!showTable) return null;
  
      return (
        <>
          <DataGrid dataSource={listData} showBorders={true} style={{padding:0,margin:0}} className="table">
              {/* column for selection of shed */}
            <Column 
            width={25}
            cellRender={record=>{
              return(record.rowIndex+1)
            }}/>
            <Column
              caption={formatMessage("Shed")}
              width={100}
              minWidth={80}
              cellRender={(record) => (
                <SelectBox
                  width={80}
                  dataSource={shedOptions}
                  displayExpr={'value'}
                  valueExpr={'value'}
                  onValueChange={e=>{
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].shed = e;
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  value={record.data.shed}
                  defaultValue={record.data.shed}
                  />
              )}
            />
            {/* selection of storage type */}
            <Column
              width={100}
              minWidth={80}
              caption={formatMessage('StorageType')}
              cellRender={(record) => (
                <SelectBox
                  dataSource={storageTypeOptions}
                  displayExpr="name"
                  valueExpr="name"
                  onValueChanged={e=>{
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                        updatedList[record.rowIndex].storageType = e.value;
                        setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  value={record.data.storageType}
                  defaultValue={record.data.storageType}
                  />
              )}
            />
  
            <Column dataField="assignedBags" caption={formatMessage("AssignedBagInTemp")} 
            cellRender={(record) => (

                <input
                  type="number"
                  defaultValue={record.data.assignedBags}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].assignedBags=parseInt(e.target.value)
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
            <Column dataField="capacity" caption={formatMessage('Capacity')} 
            cellRender={(record) => (
                <input
                  type="number"
                  defaultValue={record.data.capacity}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].capacity=parseInt(e.target.value)
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
            <Column dataField="maxBags" caption={formatMessage('MaxBags')} 
            cellRender={(record) => (
                <input
                  type="number"
                  defaultValue={record.data.maxBags}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].maxBags=parseInt(e.target.value)
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
            <Column dataField="lead" caption={formatMessage("Lead")} 
            cellRender={(record) => (
                <input
                  type="number"
                  defaultValue={record.data.lead}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].lead=parseInt(e.target.value)
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
            <Column dataField="bagsPerLayer" caption={formatMessage('BagsPerLayer')} 
            cellRender={(record) => (
                <input
                  type="number"
                  defaultValue={record.data.bagsPerLayer}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].bagsPerLayer=parseInt(e.target.value)
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
            <Column dataField="locationDescription" caption={formatMessage('LocationDescription')} 
            cellRender={(record) => (
                <textarea
                  defaultValue={record.data.locationDescription}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].locationDescription=e.target.value
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
            <Column dataField="comment" caption={formatMessage('Commentl')} 
            cellRender={(record) => (
                <textarea
                  defaultValue={record.data.comment}
                  onBlur={(e) => { 
                    const updatedList = [...listData];
                    updatedList[record.rowIndex].comment=e.target.value
                    setListData(updatedList);
                  }}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  }}
                />
            )}/>
  
            {/*  column to delete the row  */}
            <Column 
              width={50}
              cellRender={(cellData) => (
                  <Button 
                    icon="close" 
                    onClick={() => deleteRow(cellData.rowIndex)}
                    style={{borderRadius:'10%',backgroundColor:'rgba(249, 172, 156, 0.44)'}}
                    />
              )}
            />

          </DataGrid>
           <Button 
            icon="plus" 
            onClick={addRow}
            style={{borderRadius:'10%',backgroundColor:'#c7ecc7',padding:0}}
            />
        </>
      );
    };
  
    return (
      <>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(e)} />
          {formatMessage('TemporaryStack')}
        </label>
        {renderTable()}
      </>
    );
  };
```

I try to shift the column but haven't succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using datarowrender in DataGrid. So that you can able to render the data through row wise. But you won't be able to get the grid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).